# How can I fix this unexpected Windows Event Log message which appears whenever a database with FILESTREAM is created or restored?

Tags: sql-server-2014, filestream

We have recently noticed that whenever we create or restore a database with FILESTREAM enabled, a message like the following is added to the System Event Log:

> The description for Event ID 1006 from source RsFx0320 cannot be
>   found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
>   or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> \Device\RsFx0320
>
> The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file

The Event ID will be 1006 or 1007.

From the "Details" tab of Event Viewer, it's possible to see that the binary data associated with the error message contains the path of the FILESTREAM folder for the database being created/restored.

This occurs on each of our Windows 2012 R2 servers & 64-bit Standard Edition, and on my local machine running Windows 10 Pro & 64-bit Developer Edition. All of the machines are running 12.0.5203, but the issue was certainly occurring before 12.0.5203 was installed.

Unfortunately the Windows logs on the machines have cycled so it's impossible to confidently pick a date when this started.

Some research has revealed that these Event IDs probably relate to the group policy error message codes [1006](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727283%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and [1007](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727280%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

I think there are two issues here:

i) The OS is trying to verify file system permissions for a local account via group policy, but the AD controller can't be found.

ii) When i) occurs, error reporting is damaged in such a way as to prevent the proper error message being recorded in the event log.

Regarding ii) RsFx0320.sys is a Microsoft driver installed as part of the OS; I've not been able to find much information about it. I've seen a couple of suggestions that rebooting the system will clear the message but that doesn't seem to be true in this case, since instances of the error on all the servers predate the most recent restart.

Any suggestions on how to fix this/whether it needs fixing? (I don't believe the error is having any impact on the functionality of SQL Server, but it's annoying to have this message clogging up the logs.) Google has so far drawn a blank for me.

Answer (score 1):

It could be two things. If you have Windows 10, Creators update, there is a patch for the SQL Server.

In all other cases this fixed the error for me:

```
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT ON WITH NO_WAIT
GO
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET ANSI_NULLS ON WITH NO_WAIT
GO
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET ANSI_PADDING ON WITH NO_WAIT
GO
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON WITH NO_WAIT
GO
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET ARITHABORT ON WITH NO_WAIT
GO
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF WITH NO_WAIT
GO
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON WITH NO_WAIT
GO
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON WITH NO_WAIT
GO
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET PAGE_VERIFY NONE  WITH NO_WAIT
GO
```